# User friendly URL's for profiles

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following link:

```
www.website.com/profile.php?user=Test
```

I want to change the link to be:

```
www.website.com/Test
```

Where the username is after the `/` without any extra gibberish.

I have this set up in my .htaccess file, but it's not working. Why?

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /website

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're redirecting www.website.com/profile/Test in your .htaccess - that's not what you're describing in your question. What is it that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /website

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now you can access page from this URL.

```
www.website.com/Test
```

Comment: Define "not working". Not redirecting at all? Redirecting but not where you want it to? Still messing up with existing files?

Comment: @JohannesH. It's not redirecting at all. The URL stays the same.

Comment: The URL does always stay the same, it's an internal rewrite. If you want it to be external, add R to the flags. Is the right content served?

Comment: @JohannesH. How do I "add R to the flags"?

Comment: are you accessing this URL :- `www.website.com/Test` ??

Comment: Ah. SO you want the long URL to be rewritten into the short one, AND the short one to serve the content otherwise served by the long one?

Comment: @Burrows so you need to change the URL to the new.. now check this `www.website.com/Test`

Comment: `mod_rewrite` comes with apache but is not loaded by default, it must be enabled with the command `a2enmod rewrite` and then restart with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: @SumitBijvani I am on localhost, and when I go to `localhost/Test`, it gives me a 404 page.

Comment: In that case, take this answer but add another `RewriteRule ^profile.php?user=(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]` above all the RewriteConds

Comment: @Havenard I have this in the config file `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`.

Comment: @Burrows I think your website is inside the directory

Comment: @SumitBijvani What do you mean?

Comment: Ok, this doesn't lead us anywhere. @Burrows, please remove the line I just told you (to avoid circular redirection), and instead, add the R flag to this answer. That way, you should clearly see where the server redirects you to, because the URL in your browser should change.

Comment: @Burrows what is the directory structure of your website? its `localhost/yourwebsite/` or `localhost/` only?

Comment: @SumitBijvani Yes, it's `localhost/website/`, sorry.

Comment: @JohannesH. I'm still unsure of what you mean by R flag.

Comment: @Burrows So you need to change `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /website` and access Website through `localhost/website/Test`

Comment: Oh. "flags" are the things in the [] after the rule. Right now, it's `[L,QSA]`, you should make it `[R,L,QSA]`. (I know the L doesn't do anything for external rewrites, but as we want to go back to that later, we can keep it). THIS IS JUST FOR TESTING, if you got it working, remove the R again!

Comment: @SumitBijvani It's still not working. I should make it clear that the `.htaccess` file is located in `localhost/website/.htaccess` and profile.php is also in `localhost/website/profile.php`.

Comment: @Burrows its okay but as I said you need to do some changes in .htaccess file. change the rewritebase. rewritebase should be the name of your website directory

Comment: I just found out that when I go to `localhost/website/Test`, it redirects me to `localhost/website/profile.php?user=Test`. This is the exact opposite of what I want. I want it so that if they type `localhost/website/profile.php?user=Test`, it takes them to `localhost/website/Test`. What would the issue be now? I've updated my question with my current `.htaccess`.

Comment: @Burrows did you make any changes in .htaccess? just follow my given code only. see my answer.

Comment: I just tried your code, it partly works. When I go to `localhost/website/Test`, it shows the content and everything perfectly. However, when I go to `localhost/website/profile.php?user=Test`, it still doesn't redirect to `localhost/website/Test`, which is what I also need.

Comment: @Burrows you need to move to the new URL. you need to update all the website URL to the new.

Comment: @SumitBijvani I'm not sure what you mean by updating all the website URLs to the "new" one?

Comment: @Burrows you need to change the URLs to the new one like `localhost/website/Test`... `<a href="localhost/website/Test">Test</a>`

Comment: I see what you mean, but what I'm saying is that if I type `localhost/website/profile.php?user=Test` directly into the browser, it doesn't redirect to `localhost/website/Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  Test$ /profile.php?user=Test [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: For displaying the desired link as www.website.com/Test for the page www.website.com/profile.php?user=Test

Comment: It should not only work for "Test", you know :D And the line below that should actually work, and match "Test", too. SO there is really no need for the extra rule.